# click event on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click, element

I read almost everything I could find but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

```
$('.list-item').on('click', 'p', function(){
    $(this).next('.list-item small').toggle();
});
```

this code works fine if instead of `$('.list-item').on('click...'` I put an id e.g. `$('#someid').on('click...'` and I don't know why or how to get my code to work

here is my HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item">
        <p>sometext</p>
        <small>sometext</small>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <p>sometext</p>
        <small>sometext</small>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <p>sometext</p>
        <small>sometext</small>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is wrong? this work fine.

Comment: when I click the <p> it doesn't toggle the <small>. I'm talking about dynamically created elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an existing element when page load it, in this example the 
`ul` element, try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(function(){
    $("input").on("click", function(){
      $("ul").append('<li class="list-item">\
        <p>sometext</p>\
        <small>sometext</small>\
       </li>');
    });
  });
  
  $(function(){
    $('ul').on('click', 'li p', function(){
      $(this).next('.list-item small').toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Click me!">

<ul>
    <li class="list-item">
        <p>sometext</p>
        <small>sometext</small>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.list-item').on('click', 'p', function(){
    $(this).next('.list-item.small').toggle();
});
```

May be help